# How to extend toolbar functionalities with pdf.js?

Tags: webpack, pdf.js

I am currently running pdf.js to render pdf files in my web application which is managed by webpack. The pdf renderization works, but I can't figure out how to extend toolbar functionalities such as zoom in, zoom out that shows up in the top of the [default viewer](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) with my own buttons.

[image]

Checking out pdf.js examples I can see that [`viewer.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/viewer.js#L40), the script file used inside the viewer, imports a file called `app.js` which exposes a function called `PDFViewerApplication` and accept a config file where I can simply pass the buttons I'd like to behave in that way.

```
import { PDFJS, getDocument } from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

`pdfjs-dist` doesn't provide me this function... and if I try to require directly the file...

```
import { PDFViewerApplication } from 'pdfjs-dist/lib/web/app'; // throws error ENAMETOOLONG
```

What is the correct way to extend these toolbar functionalities through my own app, just using pdf.js as my pdf rendering platform?